# Searching Multiple Google Maps on 1 Page and Zoom issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

I have been getting great help today on Google Map questions and as I work through my code more stuff pop's up. So here is another question I am hoping to get help with.

There are 2 parts

**1)** I have tweaked my code to show 2 x Google Maps on the same page. My Google Maps works like this

User Searches for address and the result is

- The Map Displays a pin of locations
- Long and lat fields are populated with the coordinates
- Input field called for Office Name is populated with Search Query.

This all works when I have 1 map. But When i add a map2 to the code below, I am not sure how to write the code to split up the results between map and map2

My Code attempt is as follows (Head)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true">
    </script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var geocoder;
var map,map2;

function initialize(condition) {
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(53.2948557, -6.139267399999994);
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 10,
      center: latlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);

    map2 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas2'), mapOptions);  
 }

function codeAddress() {
    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
        document.getElementById("input_15_169").value = marker.getPosition().lat();
        document.getElementById("input_15_167").value = marker.getPosition().lng();
        document.getElementById("input_15_92").value = address;

      } else {
        alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
      }
    });
  }

</script>
```

and my body looks like this

```
<body onload="initialize()" onunload="GUnload()">
  <p>To Add your Google Map you must first plot your address by searching</p>
  <p>
    <input id="address" type="textbox" value="" placeholder="Search For Your Address">
    <input type="button" value="Plot Your Address" onclick="codeAddress()">
  </p>

  <div id="latlong">
      <p>Office Name: <input size="20" type="text" id="input_15_92" name="ofn" ></p>
      <p>Latitude: <input size="20" type="text" id="input_15_169" name="lat" ></p>
      <p>Longitude: <input size="20" type="text" id="input_15_167" name="lng" ></p>
    </div>

  <div id="map_canvas" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>

  <p>To Add your Google Map you must first plot your address by searching</p>
  <p>
    <input id="address2" type="textbox" value="" placeholder="Search For Your Address">
    <input type="button" value="Plot Your Address" onclick="codeAddress()">
  </p>

  <div id="latlong">
      <p>Office Name: <input size="20" type="text" id="input_16_92" name="ofn" ></p>
      <p>Latitude: <input size="20" type="text" id="input_16_169" name="lat" ></p>
      <p>Longitude: <input size="20" type="text" id="input_16_167" name="lng" ></p>
    </div>

  <div id="map_canvas2" style="width: 600px; height: 400px"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

I know in my current javascript above I am missing code to populate the fields for the second map which should look something like this, But I am not sure where to place them

```
document.getElementById("input_16_169").value = marker.getPosition().lat();
document.getElementById("input_16_167").value = marker.getPosition().lng();
document.getElementById("input_16_92").value = address;
```

////

**2)** The second question is to do with the zoom. I see I can set my zoom level `zoom: 10,` at the start of the code which gives the zoom level for the map. I was wondering if I can have a different zoom for when a result is found i.e. after the user searches as I would like that to be a little bit more zoomed in!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest a different markup.

Wrap the inputs and the map into a form, like this:

```
  <form style="width:220px;float:left;">
      <input name="address" value="" placeholder="Search For Your Address"/>
      <input type="button" value="Plot Your Address" onclick="codeAddress(this.form)"/>
      <input size="20" type="text"  name="ofn" />
      <input size="20" type="text" name="lat" />
      <input size="20" type="text"  name="lng" />
      <div class="map_canvas" style="width: 200px; height: 200px"></div>
  </form>
```

The benefits:

you now will be able to load the maps dynamic, without knowledge of the number of maps. you may select them easily  with `document.querySelectorAll('form>.map_canvas');` , the resulting nodeList you may use for creating the maps within a loop:

```
    var maps=document.querySelectorAll('form>.map_canvas');
    for(var i=0;i<maps.length;++i)
    {
        maps[i].parentNode.map=new google.maps.Map(maps[i], mapOptions);
    }
```

**Note:** Instead of creating the global map-variables the maps will be stored as a property of the form, so you may access the map later by using `formElement.map`

Also note the call of `codeAddress()` , it now has a argument `this.form`, it refers to the form that the clicked button belongs to.

By using this argument you are able to access the inputs and the map inside the desired form:

function codeAddress(form) {

```
var address=form.address.value
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

    form.map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: form.map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
    });
    form.map.setZoom(18);
    form.lat.value = marker.getPosition().lat();
    form.lng.value = marker.getPosition().lng();
    form.ofn.value = address;

  } else {
    alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
  }
});
```

}

The zoom may be set by using the setZoom-method af a map(it's already implemented in my suggestion)

Demo: [**http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/Tpgdd/**](http://jsfiddle.net/doktormolle/Tpgdd/)

Comment: Hi, that looks like an awesome solution, thanks for the detailed walk-through. I am going to try and implement today. I am actually using a Gravity Form and was inserting this in html in 2 different spots within the form so my html markup was not that flexible. Saying that when I read into your details today I am sure I can tweak it to work with my current fields. I hope :) thanks again

Comment: I was not sure how to contact you. You helped me above with an awesome answer and now I am looking to tweak that but running into a brick wall. Was wondering if u can take a look at my JSfiddle over here http://goo.gl/kk1td thanks